# Is there any inbuilt package in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Is there any in-built 'package' in Python or any way with which I can list all the in-built 'packages' in Python?

Note: I am not referring to modules/libraries here.

One way to distinguish between a module and package is to print it.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a Python script.
2. Create a empty directory with an empty `__init__.py` in it.
3. Import the name of the empty directory along with any inbuilt module.
4. Print both of them.

**Difference to be noted:**

The module will give an output like `<module 'itertools' (built-in)>`

whereas,

The package shall give an output like `<module 'test' (namespace)>`

Comment: You're not referring to modules? Then what are you referring to?

Comment: A module is a simple Python file. I want to know if Python has any in-built package present in its default distribution. A package is a directory that directly that at least has a file called ____init____.py

Comment: I tried searching over the internet but was unable to find one

Comment: you mean the python standard library, eg stuff like `itertools` ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Comment: Not really @frozen. To verify whether the imported module/package is a module, one can just print it. If it is a module, then it will show something like this ```<module 'itertools' (built-in)>``` else if it is a package ```<module 'test' (namespace)>```

Comment: A package is just a module that is spread over several different files.  They work exactly the same.  If you print `sys.path` in a Python shell, you can see the directories where Python looks, and you can list the contents of those directories.

Comment: Perhaps peruse this: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib Note, the distinction between a module and a package isn't very useful, always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should verify what you're looking for in [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). The package [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) for example; is a built-in package in Python. I don't know a way to show only the built-in packages, but you can see all the packages with `pip list`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are mentioning to the **Python Standard Library**, or only the the **Build-in Functions**. But yes, there are official documents for both of them, and the build-in functions are inside the standard library. I will link before so you can find it.

[The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/)
[Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to import and print `tkinter`, I got a path which lead me to directory which was apparently contained in the `lib` folder of my Python distribution. When I just went a directory up, I found many more packages. So apparently one can find all the in-built packages in their distribution by viewing the folder in the `lib` directory of their distribution.

```
<PATH_TO_DISTRIBUTION>/lib/
```

A screenshot of my **lib** directory:

[image]

**Side Note:** I just saw @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment in my question which was posted before answer got posted. So I guess I will give the credits to him for this answer.